# Mysql limit and order by

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, limit

I would like to show the last modified elements in a table, but limit the results to 5, so I did:

```
SELECT
  Id as Id,Title,LastModified
From
  articles
WHERE
  (Author=70 OR Editor=32 OR Publisher=33) && Disab ="0"

Order By   LastModified

LIMIT 0, 5
```

The problem with this query is that it is returning the first 5 rows of the table, not the last 5 edited rows...

What am I missing?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add `DESC` in the `ORDER BY` clause to sort the record in descending order.

```
ORDER BY LastModified DESC
```

by default, the `ORDER BY` clause is sorted by `ASCENDING` order.

Answer (score 1):

Default `ORDER BY` is Ascending order. You want descending

```
SELECT
  Id as Id,Title,LastModified
From
  articles
WHERE
  (Author=70 OR Editor=32 OR Publisher=33) && Disab ="0"

Order By   LastModified DESC

LIMIT 0, 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT
  Id as Id,Title,LastModified
From
  articles
WHERE
  (Author=70 OR Editor=32 OR Publisher=33) && Disab ="0"

Order By   LastModified DESC

LIMIT 0, 5
```